# Weird WriteableBitmap FromStream issue

Tags: c#, wpf, writeablebitmap, writeablebitmapex

I am desperately trying to load a `WriteableBitmap` with the `FromStream` extension method.

The code below throws a `System.InvalidOperationException` at the `FromStream()` call with the following information:

> BitmapImage has not been initialized.  Call the BeginInit method, set the appropriate properties, and then call the EndInit method.

I verified that the image exists and it's build action is set to `Resource`. The image is valid (I loaded it into a `BitmapImage`) and the stream has the correct length.

```
var sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("dummy.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
if (sri != null)
{
    using (var stream = sri.Stream)
    {
        // creates the bitmap, part of the writeablebitmapextensions on WPF
        var wb = BitmapFactory.New(1, 1); 
        wb.FromStream(stream); // <--- Exception
    }
}
```

The error seems to indicate the extension method uses a `BitmapImage` internally in an incorrect way, which I find hard to belive. I'm using `WriteableBitmapEx.Wpf 1.0.14.0`

What could be causing this exception? There is no other code running in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FromStream method in WriteableBitmapConvertExtensions.cs, line 367, seems to be broken. It is missing the `BeginInit` and `EndInit` calls on the BitmapImage:

```
public static WriteableBitmap FromStream(this WriteableBitmap bmp, Stream stream)
{
    var bmpi = new BitmapImage();
#if SILVERLIGHT
    bmpi.SetSource(stream);
    bmpi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
#elif WPF
    bmpi.StreamSource = stream;
#endif
    bmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmpi);
    return bmp;
}
```

It should look like this:

```
public static WriteableBitmap FromStream(this WriteableBitmap bmp, Stream stream)
{
    var bmpi = new BitmapImage();
#if SILVERLIGHT
    bmpi.SetSource(stream);
    bmpi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
#elif WPF
    bmpi.BeginInit();
    bmpi.StreamSource = stream;
    bmpi.EndInit();
#endif
    bmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmpi);
    return bmp;
}
```